# Unable to view the pod log with status completed

Tags: kubernetes, containers, jobs

After running a job, I noticed that some logs cannot be found while others can. It's possible that the container responsible for the missing logs was deleted. Could this have been caused by Kubernetes or was the deletion triggered during container runtime? I searched extensively for information regarding this but could not find any helpful resources.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPyo7.png)